# Chrome Extension: Event pages - are they re-run in full or only the portion related to registered events?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension

I'm transitioning from a background to an event page, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition

The docs say:

> Register to receive any events your extension is interested in each
>   time the event page is loaded. The event page will be loaded once for
>   each new version of your extension. **After that it will only be loaded
>   to deliver events you have registered for**. This generally means that
>   your event listeners should be added at the top level scope of the
>   event page, otherwise they may not be available when the event page
>   reloads.

My question is regarding to the bold part: Is the event page re-run in full after a re-activating event, or just the portion relative the handling of given event, for example the click on the browser action button.

For example, I'd like the event page to wake up when the user pushes the browser action button.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "user_clicked_browser_action_button"}, function(response) {
      });
      ga_push_event("browser_action", "browser_action_clicked");
    });
  });
```

I'm using Google Analytics and have this snippet at the bottom of my event page:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'auto');
```

Since this snippet is at the end of the page, and not called by the event listener block above, will it be processed every time *any* listening event is triggered, or do I instead have to make sure that every event listener calls the Analytics part explicitly?

Another thing I wondered, perhaps I missed it in the docs: Are we supposed to have one event page per extension or one per event?

Comment: When a registered event occurs only the event handler function runs. The entire page runs and re-registers all events in the top level code only when the user's action "wakes" the extension e.g. clicking on the extension icon or context menu etc.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, I've always liked to read your answers on CRX. Clicking on the extension icon or context menu constitutes events too. Do all events wake the extension, or only some? I assume you would suggest that the upper code "chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(..." gets executed upon click on the extension icon PLUS, the whole event page is re-run and re-registers the other events, right?

Comment: Ah, indeed, plus. Otherwise there would be no new event handler registered.

Comment: Anyway you can easily verify it yourself by logging to localStorage, for example.

Comment: Somehow my background page does not go to sleep. How can I find out what process is blocking it from being inactivated?